# How can I add a bottle deposit to a product?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have to add a bottle deposit (like an extra fee) to some bottles in the shop and have no idea how to do this.

The bottle deposit must be shown in the product view and in the shopping cart and also includes VAT.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it via adjusters, check link below.
https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/adjusters.html

In your case, you should use "tax" type for adjusters.

Comment: Thx @RomanAvr! Hm, I am not sure if or how this should work: There are different (bottle) deposits (fixed amounts, like 0,08/0,15/0,25 €) and only on some items. And these must also be displayed on the product pages and not only in the cart.

Comment: I suggest this way: 
1. Create custom field like "bottleDeposit" 
2. Add it to product type, fill it for each product and show it on frontend 
3. In tax adjuster just take bottleDeposit from your product(through lineItem)

Comment: This sounds promising, I will try to implement that the next few days ... Thx @RomanAvr - and SFLR!

Comment: Feel free to ask for help. Good luck ;)